# sqlite3 insert or replace syntax issue in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, sqlite

I am getting an error in the sqlite3 insert or replace syntax ;

My app crashes and fails to go inside the prepare_v2 statement condition.
My code is as follows :

```
NSString *plquery = @"INSERT OR REPLACE INTO LIST (COUNT, NAME, DATE, IDNUM) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) WHERE IDNUM = '";
NSString *update = [plquery stringByAppendingFormat:@"%i%@",[accessID integerValue],@"'"];
NSLog(@"%@",update);

sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [update UTF8String], -1, &stmt, nil)== SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSLog(@"reaches here");
    sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 1, i);
}
if (sqlite3_step(stmt) != SQLITE_DONE)
NSAssert1(0, @"Error updating table: %s", errorMsg);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cant have insert and where in the same statement.  You have 3 options:

1. change 'insert or replace' to 'update' if you wish to change rows that already exist.
2. remove the where statement to add new rows.
3. if your not sure if the row exists yet do a 'select' statement first then do an if else with the 2 options above.

option 1 would look like:

```
 NSString * update = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE LIST SET COUNT = ?, NAME = ?, DATE = ?, IDNUM = ? WHERE IDNUM = '%i'", [accesID integerValue]];
```

option 2 would look like:

```
NSString * update = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT OR REPLACE INTO LIST (COUNT, NAME, DATE, IDNUM) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"];
```

option 3 would look like:

```
NSString * update = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM LIST WHERE IDNUM = '%i'", [accessID integerValue]];
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
int rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [update UTF8String], -1, &stmt, nil);
if (rc == SQLITE_OK) {
    if (sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        update = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE LIST SET COUNT = ?, NAME = ?, DATE = ?, IDNUM = ? WHERE IDNUM = '%i'", [accessID integerValue]];
    }
    else{
        update = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT OR REPLACE INTO LIST (COUNT, NAME, DATE, IDNUM) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"];   
    }
}
```